# Enum with one of the values being function with &mut argument

Tags: rust

I had the following data type that worked for my code

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
  Fun(fn(X, Y) -> Z)
}
```

but I noticed that argument `Y` needs to be mutable, so I changed the signature to

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
  Fun(fn(X, &mut Y) -> Z)
}
```

and the hell went loose: it cannot deduce either of the derived traits. I was trying to add lifetimes, implementing the traits by myself, etc, but I had no luck. *What should I do for it to work again?*

Comment: Had no luck as in...you got some specific error messages?

Comment: @tadman this would be few hundred of lines of code for the whole context, I tried making the example simple.

Comment: Maybe too simple. Can you at least include the error messages for this case? It helps us focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: @tadman it's just `implementation of \`Debug\` is not general enough` and `binary operation \`==\` cannot be applied to type ...`, etc. My question is simply how to allow for such type definition. More details are that `X`, `Y`, and `Z` can basically have different lifetimes, but the function needs a broad definition, it's a kind of custom callback.

Comment: The example is reproducible, my question is how to make it compile and work the same as the earlier version of the code (without `&mut`) by accepting functions with the new signature.

Comment: You will need to implement these traits manually.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE] that produces your error. Your code doesn't show enough information for us to help you.

Comment: I agree with @PeterHall though, this function signature cannot derive `Debug` and `PartialEq` automatically. Implement those traits manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in how `std` defines the `Debug` and `PartialEq` traits. They use something like:

```rust
impl<R, A, B> Debug for fn(A, B) -> R {
    //...
}
```

Which doesn't play nice with HRTBs.

The `Clone` instance can still be derived without a problem, the rest you'll have to implement yourself:

```rust
struct X;
struct Y;
struct Z;

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
  Fun(fn(X, &mut Y) -> Z)
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        use Foo::*;
        match self {
            A => write!(f, "A"),
            B => write!(f, "B"),
            // taking inspiration from std's `Debug` impl
            Fun(fun) => write!(f, "Fun(0x{:x})", *fun as usize),
        }
    }
}

impl std::cmp::PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        use Foo::*;
        match (self, other) {
            (A, A) => true,
            (B, B) => true,
            // again taking inspiration from std
            (Fun(s), Fun(o)) => *s as usize == *o as usize,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Though you can just declare the lifetime and make `Debug` and `PartialEq` derivable as well.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
enum Foo<'a> {
  A,
  B,
  Fun(fn(X, &'a mut Y) -> Z)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d40b5bfb5b41e7571aa27220155ed3a8)